# Extra space added automatically at the end of each line in email

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I am using C# to send emails via SMTP. Email is in HTML format.

I have used following code to create message body.

```
objMailMsg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
objMailMsg.Append("<div style='margin: 20px;'>");
objMailMsg.Append("Welcome,");
objMailMsg.Append("<br /><br />Your User Name is     ");
objMailMsg.Append(emailid);
objMailMsg.Append("<br /><br />Password is     ");
objMailMsg.Append(password + "</div>");
objmail.MailMessage = objMailMsg.ToString();
```

The resultant email will be like following

> Welcome,
>
> Your User Name is username.
>
> Password is 7x*NG9p%2_

The problem is when I try to copy password it also copies extra space that is added automatically at the end (In this case in place of _) when I open this email from outlook 2003.
Previously this code didn't have "div" around the content of the email.
Adding "div" fixed this problem for outlook 2003.

I have now upgraded outlook to 2013 and this problem is back.

Can anybody please help me with how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [String.Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)

Password.Trim()
Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters.

Comment: Password doesn't have space after it. It is auto generated. Outlook is adding space after every last word of each line while formatting on its own.

Comment: p {margin: 1em 0;}
put this in your header style tag and use p tag in your html Actually p tags are inserted at rendertime, you need to overwrite it in the style tag.

Comment: Thanks Mala for your input. I have at least for now solved this problem. I have used TABLE instead of DIV. I will also try with method you stated and will post the result.

Answer (score 0):

As I have stated in comment of previous answer. At least for now I have solved this problem with the use of TABLE instead of DIV.

Use of DIV was okay when I read mails using Outlook 2003 now I have Outlook 2013. 
Both use different rendering engines IE6 rendering engine for Outlook 2003 where as MS Word for Outlook 2007 onwards which has limited support for HTML.

I don't know if this can be treated as answer but I felt I should share my findings.